# Undo changes in python

Tags: python

```
     with open('example.json', 'r+') as file:
        dict_data = json.load(file)

     for data in dict_data:

        if "field1" in data:
            
            data["field1"] = constants.FIELD1[data["field1"][0]]

        if "field2" in data:
            data["field2"] = data["field1"] + data[["field2"][0]]
            data["field2"] = constants.FIELD2[data["field1"][0]]
```

I want that `data["field1"]` to take the original value and not the value that returns in the previous line. I have changed the execution of the lines but it gives me an error.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: save it in a temporary variable

Comment: The error is that I dont need the field that is giving me. I need the original value

Comment: You have a check for null in 'if "field1" in data', but 3 lines down you don't check for null in 'data["field2"] = data["field1"] + data[["field2"][0]]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
if "field1" in data:            
    saved_key = data["field1"][0]
    data["field1"] = constants.FIELD1[data["field1"][0]]

    if "field2" in data:
        data["field2"] = data["field1"] + data[["field2"][0]]
        data["field2"] = constants.FIELD2[saved_key]
```

The second block of code only makes sense if both keys exist, so it is embedded under the first `if`.

Comment: And what if that field doesn't exist? I have a hyge json and sometimes it doesn't appear

Comment: I don't know: What value do you want to use if that field does not exist?  Only you can answer this question.

Comment: I dont want to do anythig in that case

Comment: gotcha. changed it.

Comment: By the way `["field2"][0]` is just `"field2"` . Not sure what that part of your code is supposed to do, but I left it the way you have it. Maybe you meant `data["field2"][0]`?

Comment: Another thing @alexis. Imagine that `data["field2"] = constants.FIELD2[saved_key]` give me a `key Error` because I dont have implemented that value. How could I do for not having any error in the execution?

I'm trying this:  

`if "field2" in data:
        data["field2"] = data["field1"] + data[["field2"][0]]
        data["field2"] = constants.FIELD2[saved_key]
                  if data["field2"] == None:
                  data["field2"] = 'Unknown' `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226030/discussion-between-luka-and-alexis).